# Node.js + mssql: Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, database

The question about this error has been asked multiple times, but I haven't been able to find a solution there.

I am trying to run two SQL requests simultaneously:

```
let [entityTypes, entityValues] = await Promise.all([
      db.runSqlQuery(command1), // First SQL call
      db.runSqlQuery(command2), // Second SQL call; Exception here
    ]);
```

Both SQL requests run at the same time, which seems to interfere with each other because I can't open two connections at the same time.

So I am caching the open SQL connection globally in my module:

```
var azure = require('mssql');
var pool; // connection will be cached here

// ...
var db = {
  runSqlQuery: async function (statement) {
    try {
      pool = pool || await azure.connect(this.connectionString);
      var request = new azure.Request(pool);
      var results = await request.query(statement);
      pool.close();
      return results;
    } catch (err) {
      if (pool) {
        pool.close();
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```

The way I see it, the connection should be opened the first time `runSqlQuery()` is called, and then it should be reused for the second call.

Apparently this is not what happens, since I still get this exception on the second attempt to run `runSqlQuery()`:

> Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.

How else can I make two SQL calls simultaneously?

Comment: Is it necessary to use mssql library? Because [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) supports MSSQL. This is a powerful ORM with great documentation.

Comment: May it be because, since 2 calls made simultaneously & `azure.connect(this.connectionString)` is asynchronous, for both the calls, `pool` is undefined?

Comment: In any case, I would setup the connection pool at app startup time, so that the connection would be ready to use.

Comment: @explorer I'm going to try, but this is also not guaranteed, right? Since I can't use `await` outside an async function, I can't write `var pool = await azure.connect(this.connectionString)` at the beginning of the file. That mean I will still need an async function to set it up. Which means there's still a chance both wouldn't be open.

Comment: No, you must be able to use, like how you use `async await` now. There is no difference between when that function being called.

Comment: Usually, I would make this kind asynchronous calls first, ie even before the server starts listening on the port.

Comment: Pseudo code: `setupDBConnection().then(startServer);`

Comment: Got it. Then I guess I need to restructure the whole app, because I put the database operations into a separate module which I `require` in my main code. So I guess there is no way to set up the connection first, then start the rest of the app.